# Make table data collapsible

Tags: javascript, html, css, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to make each heading part which is a table collapsible. The user should be able to click on the heading and view the table and click again to hide it. Something as simple as possible. I found something here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_collapsible.asp that seems like a lot of coding for such a simple thing. Is there a simple way to do it in HTML? I am using it in Thymeleaf as part of spring boot, so if it's done in HTML it should be easily doable in Thymeleaf too.  Following is the sample HTML that I am using.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>

    <h1> Concepts only in L1</h1>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>missing-con</th>
            <th>parent-con</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{missing-con}</td>
            <td>{parent-con}</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <h1> Concepts only in M1</h1>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>missing-con</th>
            <th>parent-con</th>
        </tr>
        <td>{missing-con}</td>
            <td>{parent-con}</td>
            <td>{missing-con}</td>
            <td>{parent-con}</td>
</table>
</body>

</html>
```

And I am looking to collapse each table. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one aproach you can addapt your way. I would advise you to add an ID/class name to the table element so you can reference it better. In this example I'm considering the first table on the document. You can also use **getElementById** or **getelementByClassName**

```
var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
var th = table.getElementsByTagName("th");
for (var i = 0; i < th.length; i++) {
    th[i].onclick = function() {
        var td = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("td");
        for (var j = 0; j < td.length; j++) {
            if (td[j].style.display == "none") {
                td[j].style.display = "";
            } else {
                td[j].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any library we could use to avoid writing this kind of repetitive code?